# leg IK weights not deforming properly

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting, inverse-kinematics, weight-paint-mode

hey sorry for the surplus of images. i am confused on why one model (the issue model) leg wont deform like the leg on the working model does even though the weights are very similar.

> [here is the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TOZY7imP4zn0GV5QB8kaB1GAt6IgIgX3/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mesh has about 2000 duplicated vertices. In consequence, the weights are messed up. When you grab one of the vertices at the knee of the issue model you will see there are rogue vertices. They are not connected and at the same spot as other vertices.

The working model has also 300 duplicated vertices.

Clean up the mesh (<kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* in *Edit* mode) and rebind the mesh to the armature with automatic weights. But first you should put the armature into rest position and clear its *Location* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in *Object* mode) and *Rotation* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). The pelvis area might need manual corrections because there are no thighs.