Problem with Rigify - Rig distorting and affecting unintended parts of the mesh
After generating a Rigify rig, some parts of the body are being affected by controls they shouldn’t be.
For example, the IK hand control moves the ear or other body parts. When I check the weight paint, affected areas appear as pink.

I’ve tried the following steps but still have issues:

Applied 'Transform All' to the mesh and metarig.
Used automatic weights, but some body parts still get influenced incorrectly.
Enabled 'Preserve Volume' in the armature modifier, but it didn’t fix the issue.
Reassigned the vertex group for the head (set other IK/FK bones to 0 influence on the head), but the issue persists.

Even when I manually try to adjust the weight paint (setting some areas to 0), the problem persists. How can I stop these unwanted influences on other parts of the mesh?
How can I find what is causing this issue?
Thank you.
Blender file here: 

the head mesh has also duplicated vertices -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253250/107598 And the body has not scale and rotation applied (Ctrl+A in Object mode). Also, your model is turned by 90° around the Z-axis so front view shows the right side and the feet controls are messed up -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/310077/107598

The head has flipped normals, so it's inside out. You need to fix it, see point 2 here:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273345/107598

@Blunder Thank you, i didn't notice that. let me try fixing those and the check out the link you shared!! I was able to fix the distortion by apply weight paint through data panel - vertex group.
